# $\epsilon$ definition of a sequence not converging to a certain number

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

I've been trying to solve a bunch of problems regarding how a sequence doesn't converge to a certain number, like how
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{2n+3}\ne1$$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+2}\ne1$$ but I don't understand the definition, how is the inequality $|L-a_n|\ge\epsilon$ going to help me find infinity $a_n$ that aren't in $(L-\epsilon, L+\epsilon)$?

Comment: You need to show that for all $N$ there is $n>N$ such that $|L-a_n| \geq \varepsilon$. This gives infinitely many $a_n$'s outside of the interval, since if there were only finitely many, taking $N$ being their largest index, produces another new $a_n$ outside the interval, which is a contradiction.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+2}\color{red}=1$. To prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{2n+3}\ne1$, choose $\epsilon>0$ small enough such that $\frac{n+1}{2n+3}\notin(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$ for infinitely many $n$s. Here, any $\epsilon\le1/2$ will do since $$\frac{n+1}{2n+3}<1-\epsilon\iff\epsilon<\frac12+\frac1{2(2n+3)}.$$